# can not sort on a field w/o docValues unless it is indexed=true uninvertible=true and the type supports Uninversion

Tags: solr, tridion

We are using SOLR with SI4T for TRIDION 8.5. Recently updated SOLR V5 to V8 and updated schemas as well. rest of the collections sorting works fine but for a particular collection(site) we are unable to sort the records using `sort_title` field. Schema remains same for all the collection.

```
 <fields>
    <field name="sort_title" type="alphaOnlySort" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
 </fields>
    <copyField source="short_title" dest="sort_title" />
```

On executing a query, I see the following logs on SOLR console.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":400,
    "QTime":29,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "sort":"sort_title asc",
      "_":"1584444920249"}},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"c**an not sort on a field w/o docValues unless it is indexed=true uninvertible=true and the type supports Uninversion: sort_title**",
    "code":400}}
```

**Stack Trace on Console**

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: can not sort on a field w/o docValues unless it is indexed=true uninvertible=true and the type supports Uninversion: sort_title
    at org.apache.solr.schema.SchemaField.checkSortability(SchemaField.java:194)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType.getSortedSetSortField(FieldType.java:725)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType.getStringSort(FieldType.java:772)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.StrField.getSortField(StrField.java:87)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.SchemaField.getSortField(SchemaField.java:154)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SortSpecParsing.parseSortSpecImpl(SortSpecParsing.java:202)
    at org.apache.solr.search.SortSpecParsing.parseSortSpec(SortSpecParsing.java:60)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getSortSpec(QParser.java:281)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:302)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:211)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2596)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:799)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:578)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:419)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Any help apriciated!!

**Issue resolved**

It was really stupid ignorance. Whenever you get "can not sort on a field w/o docValues", please check the query output fields. In my case `sort_title` was never indexed due to some inavlid character in the `schema.xml`. After correcting the schema and reindexing the core it had `sort_title` field and sorting was working as expected.

Comment: If uninvertible = true, indicates that an indexed="true" docValues="false" field can be "un-inverted" at query time to build up large in memory data structure to serve in place of DocValues. Defaults to true for historical reasons, but users are strongly encouraged to set this to false for stability and use docValues="true" as needed.

Comment: So whats the conclusion here @AbhijitBashetti? I tried to enable DocValues for the field but no joy!

Comment: disable uninvertible and enable docvalues...

Comment: I changed the properties of the field but no luck!